# Explicitly calling the autocomplete function in jquery autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a text field to which I have a jquery autocomplete event attached. However, due to some reasons, I dont want the search results to appear when the user types, but rather when a button is pressed. I know this sounds lame, but I have my reasons. How do I trigger the autosearch results to appear by calling an explicit function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of autocomplete you are using.  If you use the [latest version which is rolled into jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) you can use the *search* method:

> Search :: Signature:
>       .autocomplete( "search" , [value] )
>
> Triggers a search event, which, when
>   data is available, then will display
>   the suggestions; can be used by a
>   selectbox-like button to open the
>   suggestions when clicked. If no value
>   argument is specified, the current
>   input's value is used. Can be called
>   with an empty string and minLength: 0
>   to display all items.